# Doubts regarding making a sync between database and selectinput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to make a sync between my database `df` and the two selectinput I created, in other words, when I run the APP, I can show the d1 and d2 values in the two selectinput. Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(df){
    
    
    df <- structure(
        list(date = c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03","2021-01-04","2021-01-05"),
             d1 = c(0,1,4,5,6), d2 = c(2,4,5,6,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
}    
    ui <- fluidPage(
        
        ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                                br(),
                                
                                tabPanel("",
                                         sidebarLayout(
                                             sidebarPanel(
                                                                                                     
                                                selectInput("d1", label = h4("D1"),""),
                                                 selectInput("d2", label = h4("D2"),""),
                                                 
                                             ),
                                             
                                             mainPanel(
                                             ))
                                )))
    
    
server <- function(input, output,session) {
        
}
    
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try -

```
library(shiny)

function.cl<-function(){
  
  df <- structure(
    list(date = c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03","2021-01-04","2021-01-05"),
         d1 = c(0,1,4,5,6), d2 = c(2,4,5,6,7)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
}    
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       selectInput("d1", label = h4("D1"),""),
                                       selectInput("d2", label = h4("D2"),""),
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl())
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "d1", label = "D1", unique(data()$d1))
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "d2", label = "D2", unique(data()$d2))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```